# Why aggregate query with lookup is extremely slow?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have a mongodb query that works but takes too long to execute and causes my CPU to spike to 100% while it is executing.  It is this query here:

```
  db.logs.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
      {
        from: 'graphs',
        let: { logId : '$_id' },
        as: 'matched_docs',
        pipeline:
          [
            {
              $match: {
                $expr: {
                  $and: [
                    { $eq: ['$$logId', '$lId'] },
                    { $gte: [ '$d', new Date('2020-12-21T00:00:00.000Z') ] },
                    { $lt: [ '$d', new Date('2020-12-23T00:00:00.000Z') ] }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ],
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $and: [
            { $eq: [ '$matched_docs', [] ] },
            { $gte: [ '$createDate', new Date('2020-12-21T00:00:00.000Z') ] },
            { $lt: [ '$createDate', new Date('2020-12-23T00:00:00.000Z') ] }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    { $limit: 5 }
  ]);
```

This query looks for all records in the `db.logs` collection for which they have not been transformed and loaded into `db.graphs`.  It's analogous to this SQL approach:

```
WHERE db.logs._id NOT IN (
        SELECT lId FROM db.graphs
        WHERE db.graphs.d >= @startTime
        AND db.graphs.d < @endTime
    )
    AND db.logs.createDate >= @startTime
    AND db.logs.createDate < @endTime
)
```

The `db.logs` has over 1 Million records and here are the indexes:

```
db.logs.getIndexes();
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "createDate" : 1
                },
                "name" : "createDate_1"
        }
]
```

And `db.reportgraphs` has fewer than 100 records with indexes on every property/column.

In my attempt to analyze why the mongo query is so slow and CPU intensive, I suffixed my mongo query with a `.explain()`.  But mongo gave me the error saying `db.logs.aggregate(...).explain() is not a function`.  I also tried adding `, {$explain: 1}` immediately after `{ $limit: 5}` and got an error saying `Unrecognized pipeline stage name $explain`.

So I guess I have two questions:

1. Can someone give feedback on why my  mongo query is so slow or possible solutions?
2. Is there a way to see the execution plan of my mongo query so that I can review where the performance bottle necks are?

---

UPDATE

A possible solution I'm considering is to have a property `db.logs.isGraphed:boolean` .  Then use a simple `db.logs.find({isGraphed:false, createDate:{...date filter...}}).limit(5)`.  Wasn't sure if this is the approach most people would have considered in the first place?

Comment: You get the execution plan with `db.logs.explain.aggregate([...` or ``db.logs.explain().aggregate([...``

Comment: or use `db.logs.aggregate([...], {explain: 1})` (without dollar sign and after the actual pipeline)

Comment: What are the indexes on `graphs` collection?

Comment: Replace the match by `$match: {matched_docs: [], createDate:{ $gte: new Date(...), $lt: new Date(...)}}`

Comment: Unlike most relational RDBMS the MongoDB (and other NoSQL) database system is not designed or optimized for joins, some NoSQL databases even do not support joins at all. You may write a separate query on `graphs`, store the result in an array and use this array at `$match: { _id: {$nin: ...}, createDate: ...}` operator.

Answer (score 0):

It is slow because it is not using an index.  For each document in the `logs` collection, it is doing a full collection scan on the `graphs` collection.

From the [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) documentation page:

> $expr only uses indexes on the from collection for equality matches in a $match stage.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried `explain` on compass for `lookup` stage, and for this kind of lookup stage, it turned out that defining the `foreignField/localField` as a variable with `let` and adding it into the `pipeline` makes the query so slow. so please try this:
I believe you will see the improvement in the performance after this change, also do not forget to add proper indexes, they are super helpful.

```
$lookup:
      {
        from: 'graphs',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'lId'
        as: 'matched_docs',
        pipeline:
          [
            {
              $match: {
                $expr: {
                  $and: [
                    { $gte: [ '$d', new Date('2020-12-21T00:00:00.000Z') ] },
                    { $lt: [ '$d', new Date('2020-12-23T00:00:00.000Z') ] }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ],
      }
```